# What is the relation between FreeType, Fontconfig and Xft

Tags: fonts, linux

I just started research on how fonts work under Linux. Till now, I got to know that the Linux font system consists of:

- FreeType, which is a rasterizer for rasterizing vector-based text to bitmap-based.
- Fontconfig, which is a library for managing and locating fonts inside the operating system.
- Xft that is used for displaying desired output on X windows system or so.

(Correct me if I am wrong.)

Is there any direct relation between these three? What is the workflow? And under what circumstances these system libraries are invoked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're related like this (using `ldd`):

- `Xft` is a library, which depends on (among other things) the `fontconfig` library and the `freetype` library.
- `fontconfig` is a set of programs, a library and data.  Its library depends upon the `freetype` library.
- `freetype` is a library, which does not depend on the other two.

For example:

```
$ ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXft.so.2.3.1
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffb3df7000)
        libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f40ea07a000)
        libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f40e9ddb000)
        libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f40e9bd1000)
        libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f40e9896000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f40e9509000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f40e92f2000)
        libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f40e90c8000)
        libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f40e8ea8000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f40e8ca4000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f40ea4c6000)
        libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f40e8aa1000)
        libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f40e889c000)
```

Some applications (such as `xterm`) use `Xft`, which uses an MIT-license.  Others (generally the GPL-licensed ones) use `libpango`.  Besides licensing concerns on *pango*, it has twice as many library-dependencies as `Xft`.

Looking at the symbols from `fontconfig` used by `Xft`:

```
FcCharSetCopy
FcCharSetCount
FcCharSetDestroy
FcCharSetHasChar
FcConfigGetBlanks
FcConfigSubstitute
FcDefaultSubstitute
FcFontList
FcFontMatch
FcFreeTypeCharIndex
FcFreeTypeCharSet
FcInit
...
FcPatternPrint  
FcPatternVaBuild  
FcStrCmpIgnoreCase
FcUtf16ToUcs4
FcUtf8ToUcs4
```

and those from `freetype`:

```
FT_Done_Face
FT_GlyphSlot_Embolden
FT_Init_FreeType
FT_Library_SetLcdFilter
FT_Load_Glyph
FT_New_Face
FT_Render_Glyph
FT_Set_Char_Size
FT_Set_Transform
FT_Vector_Transform
```

you can see that `Xft` uses `fontconfig` for locating fonts based on *patterns*, but uses `freetype` to actually *load*, *display* or *adjust* (scale, etc) a font.

`fontconfig` uses different calls to `freetype` to obtain information about a font (the overall size, the number of glyphs, etc):

```
FT_Done_Face
FT_Done_FreeType
FT_Get_BDF_Property
FT_Get_Char_Index
FT_Get_First_Char
FT_Get_Glyph_Name
FT_Get_Next_Char
FT_Get_PS_Font_Info
FT_Get_Sfnt_Name
FT_Get_Sfnt_Name_Count
FT_Get_Sfnt_Table
FT_Get_X11_Font_Format
FT_Has_PS_Glyph_Names
FT_Init_FreeType
FT_Load_Glyph
FT_Load_Sfnt_Table
FT_New_Face
FT_Select_Charmap
FT_Select_Size
```

Without `freetype`, `fontconfig` hasn't any information: `fontconfig` *organizes* information but is not a complete *source* of information by itself.

Comment: fine much better. can u please tell what is the main relationship between fontconfig and Freetype? I mean if i do fc-list or any stuff like that, is it dependent of Freetype? In which scenarios Fontconfig calls FreeType?

Comment: Just to make sure what i learned is correct. FreeType is a library that is mainly responsible for digging deep in a font file and taking out the low level information like face, Cmap, glyph details etc. ? And font config is a high level API which usually do the management and location of fonts in Linux operating system?

Comment: that's close enough

Comment: FreeType does font glyph-by-glyph rendering, Fontconfig does font matching. Fontconfig helps you find the right font, FreeType lets you actually use it.